# How can I ask for a Schengen visa that would be valid for 1 year?

Tags: visas, schengen, hungary

How could I indicate in the visa application that I want the visa to be valid for 1 year and with a 90-day duration of stay? I don't know how to show that. Do I do it by the dates of the first and last entries?

Answer (score 8):

When you apply for a Schengen visa, you have to explain the **premise** of your trip. That means you explain *where* you want to go, *when* you want to go, *what* you are doing there, *who pays* for the trip, and *why* the visa officials should believe that you will return to your home country. Your should have a planned date of travel for that.

Typically on the first couple of visa applications you get a **single-entry** visa with perhaps a few days more validity than your planned trip. Once you have a travel history in Schengen, without overstays or other incidents, and if you appear reliable, you might get a multi-entry visa with a longer validity (but still limited to 90/180).

If you cannot say when in the next year you plan to make the trip, the application seems rather weak for a first-time visitor.

Answer (score 1):

I recently applied for a Greece Schengen visa and was granted a 1 year type C multiple entry visa to the Schengen area. Below are some suggestions that worked for me.

1) This was my third Schengen visa.
2) I was a permanent resident of Canada at the time of application. Before, when I applied for my second Schengen visa in New York, the Finnish consulate was hesitant in issuing a long term visa as I was on a temporary work permit that was expiring the same year. They did issue me the visa, but it was for the exact dates of the trip I'd shown.
3) I had travel insurance for 1 year, it is actually cheaper if you get it 2 times or more within a year.
4) I politely requested the visa officer for a 1 year visa and showed her copies of my previous Schengen visas. She made a note of it, and said she'll take that into account.

PS: My Parents in India also got the same 1 year visa, the second time they applied, so it really depends on the consulate, but hopefully these pointers might help someone.